# Cant export coordinates on Folium draw polygon in Pyqt5 app

Tags: python, pyqt5, draw, folium

Im writing app in pyqt5 using folium to mark some area and get gps coordinates. App works I can draw polygon shape but when Im clicking Export button nothing happend. Maybe someone had similiar problem and knows why?

```
import folium, io, sys
from folium.plugins.draw import Draw
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets

class Mapy(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.interfejs()

    def interfejs(self):
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.webEngineView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        self.loadPage()
        vbox.addWidget(self.webEngineView)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('mapy')
        self.show()

    def loadPage(self):
        m = folium.Map(
            location=[51.7687323,19.4569911], zoom_start=5
        )
        Draw(
            export=True,
            filename='my_data.geojson',
            position='topleft',
            draw_options={'polyline': False, 'rectangle': False,'circle':False, 'circlemarker':False},
            edit_options={'poly': {'allowIntersection': False}}
        ).add_to(m)
        data = io.BytesIO()
        m.save(data, close_file=False)
        self.webEngineView.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    okno = Mapy()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manage the downloads using the [`downloadRequested`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineprofile.html#downloadRequested) signal from the page profile:

```py
import io
import sys

import folium
from folium.plugins.draw import Draw

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class Mapy(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.interfejs()

    def interfejs(self):
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.webEngineView = QWebEngineView()
        self.webEngineView.page().profile().downloadRequested.connect(
            self.handle_downloadRequested
        )
        self.loadPage()
        vbox.addWidget(self.webEngineView)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle("mapy")
        self.show()

    def loadPage(self):
        m = folium.Map(location=[51.7687323, 19.4569911], zoom_start=5)
        Draw(
            export=True,
            filename="my_data.geojson",
            position="topleft",
            draw_options={
                "polyline": False,
                "rectangle": False,
                "circle": False,
                "circlemarker": False,
            },
            edit_options={"poly": {"allowIntersection": False}},
        ).add_to(m)
        data = io.BytesIO()
        m.save(data, close_file=False)
        self.webEngineView.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())

    def handle_downloadRequested(self, item):
        path, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
            self, "Save File", item.suggestedFileName()
        )
        if path:
            item.setPath(path)
            item.accept()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    okno = Mapy()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @moj_nowy  If answer helped you then do not forget to mark as correct, 
if you do not know how to do it then check the https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Hi I have some issue with developing my app. I wish to read file automaticly after it was downloaded. I deleted all from function handle_downloadRequested() exepted item.accept(). It works - file is saved to the current folder without asking. Than I add function to read that file but app crashed and sais that there is no file. And its true file is not saved. I thought maybe it needs some time so I did time.sleep(10) to be sure that line item.accept() has enought time to write it but nothing hanged. Dont understund why. Any ideas?

Comment: def handle_downloadRequested(self, item):
        item.accept()
        openJson()

    def openJson(self):
        with open('my_data.geojson') as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
            print(data)

Comment: @moj_nowy 1) I recommend you read the docs, the accept method only indicates that the download starts. 2) You should never use time.sleep in a GUI., 3) The "item" which is QWebEngineDownloadItem has a finished signal that indicates that the download finished

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks for a tip. Everything works now :)
    def handle_downloadRequested(self, item):
        item.finished.connect(self.openJson)
        item.accept()